# MVC Model Binding Persisting Complex Properties on Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have the following setup

```
public class Profile
{
    //Some Properties

    //Some Methods
}

/*Model Class*/
public class LineItem
{
    public Profile Profile {get;set;}
}
```

In my controller. I have the two following Actions

```
public ActionResult GetRequest(){

    LineItem model = new LineItem();
    model.Profile = new Profile(){/*Initialize Properties*/};
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult PostRequest(LineItem item(){
      item.Profile ....  /*Profile Is Null*/
      return View(...);
}
```

I have verified that the Profile property on the LineItem model class is set on the GetRequest, and returned to the view, but I want to know how to persist that complex property when that model is submitted. I know that people typically use hidden fields for model persistance, and that the session is also available, but it seems that I should be able to tell the ModelBinder sometimes (possibly through an attribute or annotation) to persist complex properties on my model.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried to create a custom Model Binder that implements the IModelBinder interface?

Comment: The default `ModelBinder` will set any property that matches a POST parameter. So if you don't have an input element for a particular property, it won't persist between GET/POST.

Comment: I was planning on doing this, but I want to determine a way to make this process fairly transparent. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Profile.Id)` `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Profile.Name)` etc. for each property of Model.Profile you need to persist. You shouldn't touch model binder - it will be binded automatically by using standart model binder.
If you use other html helpers, that generates input tags for some property - you shouldn't use `@Html.HiddenFor()` for this property.

Comment: this would not work, if you look at my question, I am not worried specifically just about the Id, I am worried about the entire Profile property. If I was to use this method, I would need to provide a hidden input for each property which is not very practical for large complex objects.

Comment: If it is a problem, you can write your own serialization logic for profile class, use hidden field to store this serialization, and create your custom model binder for this class to deserialize hidden field into properties. BUT it looks like ViewState in webforms. Think about your profile class is SO complicated to do all this work and you need to reuse this solution for other classes. Using N-time Html.Hidden call is more easy way.